# What replaces Monaco Editor's deprecated deltaDecorations function?

Tags: monaco-editor

The document says it's deprecated:

```
(method) editor.ICodeEditor.deltaDecorations(oldDecorations: string[], newDecorations: monaco.editor.IModelDeltaDecoration[]): string[]
All decorations added through this call will get the ownerId of this editor.

@deprecated

The signature '(oldDecorations: string[], newDecorations: IModelDeltaDecoration[]): string[]' of 'editor.deltaDecorations' is deprecated.
```

but the only example I found still uses it

https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#interacting-with-the-editor-line-and-inline-decorations

The document doesn't say anything about what replaced it.

Comment: Something between 0.30 and 0.34 has also broken my `hoverOverlay` content. Nothing gets put on the screen at present

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md,

> Soft deprecation of ICodeEditor.deltaDecorations, no adoption required. IEditor.createDecorationsCollection API should be used instead.

Comment: What garbage nonsense by Microsoft. `createDecorationsCollection` doesn't do what `deltaDecorations` did. There's no longer a way to remove decorations.

Answer (score 0):

`createDecorationsCollection` returns a `monacoT.editor.IEditorDecorationsCollection` which has a `.clear()` method to remove all prior decorations.